# cmake doesn't correctly run in a Bamboo script

Tags: cmake, cygwin, bamboo

I want to run an inline script that executes cmake command to generate the build files for my c/c++ unit tests. The Bamboo agent runs on a Windows 10 OS. I installed cygwin on the Agent's server to have cmake up and running. 
If I run cmake directly on prompt, on the Agent's server, everything works fine.
If I run the same command in my Bamboo script I get the following error:

```
I:\bamboo-agent-home\xml-data\build-dir\CIMX-XFU-JOB1>cmake . -Bbuild  
-- CMAKE_BINARY_DIR=/cygdrive/i/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/CIMX-XFU-JOB1/build
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.14.5/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/bin/gcc.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /cygdrive/i/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/CIMX-XFU-JOB1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make.exe cmTC_7f576/fast
    /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_7f576.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_7f576.dir/build
    make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/i/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/CIMX-XFU-JOB1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_7f576.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
    /usr/bin/gcc.exe    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_7f576.dir/testCCompiler.c.o   -c /cygdrive/i/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/CIMX-XFU-JOB1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
    C:/cygwin64/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/cc1.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_7f576.dir/build.make:66: CMakeFiles/cmTC_7f576.dir/testCCompiler.c.o] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/i/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/CIMX-XFU-JOB1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_7f576/fast] Error 2

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:34 (project)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/cygdrive/i/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/CIMX-XFU-JOB1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/cygdrive/i/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/CIMX-XFU-JOB1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

CMake tries to compile a simple C application in order to test the gcc compiler, but it fails.
I tried to compile the same application using gcc and it works.
It seems there is a problem between cmake and Bamboo.

In the Bamboo script, I include the path to cygwin(C:\cygwin64\bin) into the environment variable PATH

Any idea on what can cause the issue?

Comment: `C:/cygwin64/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/cc1.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?` - Something wrong with your cygwin compiler. This error means your system lacks for some(!) libraries required by that compiler. You may run `C:/cygwin64/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/cc1.exe` directly and you will get same results.

Comment: If I run C:/cygwin64/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/cc1.exe on testCCompiler.c, it works fine. It doesn't work if it runs within CMake. The problem is that for some reasons CMake can't find those libraries when it runs within the Bamboo's context.

Comment: "The problem is that for some reasons CMake can't find those libraries when it runs within the Bamboo's context." - It is not CMake who search libraries for run the compiler. Something wrong with your Bamboo's context or the compiler installation under it.

Comment: This is likely due to permission problems on the network drive `The C compiler     "/usr/bin/gcc.exe"  is not able to compile a simple test program.` Try to build under the Cgwin tree. `/tmp` or `/usr/src` are possible place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem. Bamboo allows to overwrite environmental variables for a specific testing plan. I redefined PATH adding the path to the Cygwin executables, doing so, CMake can access all the libraries and the executables needed.
CMake before generating the build files tests that the C compiler works running a small test application. CMake generates a Makefile that builds and executes this test application. For reasons I still don't understand, the Makefile doesn't have visibility of my redefinition of the environment variable PATH, but it reads Bamboo's original version of PATH. 
In order to solve the problem, I had to change Bamboo's environment variable PATH.

Answer (score 0):

could you plz let me know heere to do it in bamboo, weill I am facing problem that cmake does not start at all, it gives errors

```
Failed to run MSBuild command: C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/12.0/bin/MSBuild.exe
to get the value of VCTargetsPath:
```

while it runs fine on standalone windows machine (this machine is configured as agent)

Comment: You need to add cmake as a capability of your agent. https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/defining-a-new-custom-capability-289277149.html